# Como pegar velores dados do Wordpress usando wpdb->get_results

Tags: php, wordpress

Pessoal o codigo abaixo ele lista os resultados sem repetir o post porem  preciso que ele list que contem o campo personalizado  com os seguintes valores: 
 meta_key "tipo" 
 meta_value "lanche"

```html
<?php
    global $wpdb, $table_prefix;
    $arquivos = $wpdb->get_results( '
        SELECT *
        FROM '.$table_prefix.'posts
        WHERE
            post_type = "arquivos"
            AND post_status = "publish"
        GROUP BY post_title
    ' );
?>
<?php foreach ( $arquivos as $key => $value ): ?>
    <?php echo $value->post_title ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Por que está utilizando SQL diretamente no código? Você pode fazer qualquer consulta com WP_Query

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer essa consulta usando [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'arquivos',
    'post_status' => array('publish'),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'tipo',
            'value'   => 'lanche',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
);

$arquivos = new WP_Query($args);
foreach ($arquivos as $key => $value){
    echo $value->post_title;
}
```